# Journey Builder email send errors

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

The entry source is a filtered data extension that is being refreshed every hour through Automation Studio for my Journey.

After successful validation and activation, the journey email icon shows values being added but the journey reporting is showing "zero" sends. Please note that the schedule for the journey is set from 8 am to 5 pm.

Also, I have another Journey in which it is using a batch send of 50K static data extension and an entry source and throttled for 2500 per hour from 8 am to 5 pm. This email deploys but somehow errors out after sending two batches -- approximately 5000. We tried to pull this out of Journey and do a manual user-initiated send. Not sure if throttling and a deployment cap window is causing an issue.

Comment: How long after did you look at the journey reporting?  That is known to lag a bit.  What timezone are you in?  You may need to ensure that your SFMC account is configured locally as by default it is set to US - CT (without observation of DLST)

Comment: Thakks Adam - Seems like the journey was tied to an older version - We built the Journey from Scratch and scheduled it based on linking to Automation -